# UPDATE column based ID

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table with two columns, ID and Email Address.

```
ID   EMAIL
-------------------------
1    no-reply@company.com  
2    no-reply@company.com
3    no-reply@company.com
4    no-reply@company.com
```

I now have a list of emails to update based on their ID. Each email is unique.

I have updated multiple fields before with a query like

```
 INSERT IGNORE INTO `table` (`column1`, `column2`) VALUES
 (0001,0002),
 (0004,0004),
```

Is there a way to use a similar concept while updating the emails with their specific ID?

Comment: not really because you need a separate WHERE clause for each row. You'll set the same value for each row which matches the WHERE clause. If the number of matched rows is 1 (because your WHERE clause restricts by ID), then you'll need another query to set another row. There's not really any way to shorten that.

Answer (score 0):

To update multiple emails when you have their ids, you can use SQL IN operator.
Learn more here: [SQL IN Operator](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp)

Comment: not if each email is unique - OP states that in the question

Answer (score 0):

Using `Update` queries is the simplest way to edit records that belong to another Update table:

```
UPDATE tbl1, tbl2 SET tbl1.mail = tbl2.mail
WHERE tbl1.id = tbl2.id;
```

Comment: The emails are not from another table, they were just provided to me in a list.